# How to display validation message on the browser in web.py python

Tags: python, validation, web.py

I am using web.py framework for designing a small web application, presently i have created a login page and code is below

**index.py**

```
import web
from web import form
from web.contrib.auth import DBAuth
import MySQLdb as mdb

render = web.template.render('templates/')


urls = (
  '/',   'Login',
  '/projects',  'Projects',
  '/logout',   'Logout',
)

app = web.application(urls, globals()) # Creating an instance(object) app which is the mediator between our classes and the web.It will handle browser requests and serve your pages

web.config.debug = False
db = web.database(dbn='mysql', db='Python_Web', user='root', pw='redhat')
settings = {}

if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    session = web.session.Session(app,web.session.DiskStore('sessions'),initializer={'user':'anonymous','loggedin':False})
    web.config._session = session
else:
    session = web.config._session

auth = DBAuth(app, db, session,**settings)


def logged():
    if session['loggedin'] == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
class Login:

    # field validators
    username_required = form.Validator("Username not provided", bool)
    password_required = form.Validator("Password not provided", bool)

    # form validators
    login_details_required = form.Validator("Please Enter Login Details", lambda f: f["username"] or f["password"])

    login_form = form.Form( 
        form.Textbox('username', username_required),
        form.Password('password',password_required,description="Password"),
        form.Button('Login'),
        )

    def GET(self):
        if logged():
            raise web.seeother('/projects')
        else:
            form = self.login_form()
            return render.login(form)

    def POST(self):

        if not my_form.validates(dict(username="", password="small")):
            return render.login(form)

        i = web.input()
        username = i.username.strip()
        password = i.password.strip()
        user = auth.authenticate(username, password)
        if not user:
            session.loggedin = False
            return render.login_error(form) 
        else:
            auth.login(user)
            session.loggedin = True
            session.user = i.username.strip()
            raise web.seeother('/projects')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.internalerror = web.debugerror
    app.run()
```

Here in the above code my intention is

1.If username not provided it should display `"Username not provided"` when clicked on Login

2.If password not provided it should display `"password not provided"` when clicked on Login

3.If password provided  but length is less than 7 characters it should display `"Password length should be minimum 7 characters"` when clicked on Login(Of course this validation concept suits when `creating a user` by selecting password )

4.If Both not provided  it should display `"Please Enter Login Details"` when clicked on Login

5.If Login details not matched it should display `"Invalid Username or Password"` when clicked on Login and if login Details matched should redirect to next page

In the above code when login details matched its redirecting to next page successfully and if not displaying `Invalid username or password` through `return render.login_error(form)` (I copied same html code from `login(form)` page to  `login_error(form)` and added `"Invalid Username or Password"` line extra in that)

Also i created a `regex` expression for password validation and hope thats working(I dint checked exactly) because if password length is less than 7 characters it is not redirecting to next page instead redirecting to same login page, but at the same time i want to display on the browser like the message `"Password length should be minimum 7 characters"` which i am unable to do(dont know how to do)

Also i had given username as `form.notnull()` validation in `Form` creation as above, when i tried to click login it is checking whether the form validates or not and if not redirecting to the same login page, but i want to display the message `"Please enter the username"` and also for password if not provided

1. Whether the above regex will work correctly (i dint worked on regex until now)
2. How to display the above validation messages on browser if username,password, not provided on the browser, because i had created another html page just for the `Invalid username or password` message to appear on the browser when details are incorrect

Whether we can do all this validations in single html file(like `login.html`) itself ? ,
i have tried a lot but i am unable catch the process going on here, if so we can save of creating more than one html for individual messages

can anyone let me know on how to solve the above common problems ?
Don't mind for my queries as this is my first step in web applications and i dint worked on web applications before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add many validators to the same input field and there are also form level validations.

```
from web import form


# field validators
username_required = form.Validator("Username not provided", bool)
password_required = form.Validator("Password not provided", bool)
password_length = form.Validator("Password length should be minimum 7 characters", lambda p: p is None or len(p) >= 7)

# form validators
login_details_required = form.Validator("Please Enter Login Details", lambda f: f["username"] or f["password"])

def check_login(f):
    # check for login here
    return False
valid_credentials = form.Validator("Invalid username or password", check_login)

login_form = form.Form(
    form.Textbox('username', username_required),
    form.Password('password', password_required, password_length, description="Password"),
    form.Button('Login'),
    validators=[login_details_required, valid_credentials],
)


my_form = login_form()
if not my_form.validates(dict(username="", password="small")):
    print my_form.render_css()

if not my_form.validates(dict(username="notnull", password="just-enough")):
    print my_form.render_css()
```

Note that `login_details_required` won't be triggered, because form-level validation is only triggered when all fields validators have passed.

Comment: K i have edited code and as of now i want to check only two conditions, username and password that is if username not given or password not given,a message should display on the browser like"Please enter Username" and "Please enter Password", But when i run the code and checked by clicking login button with username and and without password, but its not displaying the message "please enter the password" on the browser.

Comment: Whether we need to design these messages in login.html(render.login(form)) to display on the browser? or whether there is any wrong in my above code? whether we need to check this in get method or post method ?

Comment: If u don't mind can u please add or correct this functionality code in my complete code pasted above as this is first web designing application and will design myself from the next time....

Comment: There is a working example of form on webpy website, check this: http://webpy.org/cookbook/forms

Comment: yup.. i got the point where its not working. Actually after creating a login_form in the above code i am sending in to render.login(login_form), but i am not rendering it in html page like $:login_form.render,i created separate html for login page in index.html for username,password,login button.But actually i don't want to render it, i want to create my own html and functionality should work,is it possible to validate and display these messages on the browser with rendering $:form.render() in index.html ?

Comment: And one more problem is i tried the above example as it is and it worked fine and displayed validation messahes when username,password not given, here even though after when we refresh the page the messages are appearing on the screen, i mean once they appeared on the screen they are not removed even though i refreshed my page in browser

Comment: 1) If you want to write your own html for forms you either subclass webpy form and provide your own render method, or you may render individual form fields in your html (http://webpy.org/cookbook/form_fields). Validation messages are stored in `form.note` and `form.your_input_name.note` 2) If you refresh POST request, it will be submitted once again and so validation will run once more.